# Installing GMP math library

Tags: c++, math, gmp

How do I use GMP in Codeblocks in Windows? I have looked all over the internet and have found no instructions on how to do so.

- All the instructions I have found are for VC++ and are completely out of date.
- The instructions in the readme are all for linux, making it useless for me. windows does not know how to run a `.autoconfig` file and neither do I.
- There is no folder to add into my search directories for the compiler, unless it is the entire gmp folder itself. There is no lib or includes folder anywhere
- Also, there is no "gmp.h" file anywhere in the downloaded tar.gz or tar.bz, so I have no idea how to include it in my programs

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/). This is a fork of GMP with one of the stated aims being better Windows support.

In my experience <sup>a</sup>, they're also a much more open group to deal with, both for users of their library and developers wishing to contribute.

In other words, even if they don't have *explicit* documentation for Code::Blocks, you'll get a lot more help on the subject from them.

---

<sup>a</sup>: Keep in mind that this is from only a couple of messages on the forums when I tried to suggest some changes (stopping it from violently exiting on out-of-memory conditions, a fatal flaw in my opinion for a general purpose library). While the GMP head honcho seemed to dismiss other opinions as raving lunacy, the MPIR folks went out of their way to track me down and talk through the possibilities.